# How to read Instagram Web Structure using JS and tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, instagram, tampermonkey

Hi I have been trying to create a script for specifically https://www.instagram.com/direct/* using tampermonkey
What I am trying to achieve is whenever I get a new message regardless of who it is from, It sends a ping sound (just like discord or telegram)

I am new to js and most of my learning is from StackOverflow, GitHub or articles, so far I have tried inspecting networks, inspecting dom but none of it works successfully

One of my tries:-

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name Focus Instagram Direct Text Input and New DM Sound
// @namespace https://www.instagram.com/
// @description Focuses the text input field and plays a bell sound whenever a new direct message is received on Instagram Direct.
// @include https://www.instagram.com/*
// @version 1.0
// @grant GM_addStyle
// @grant GM_getResourceURL
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    // Function to play the bell sound
    function playSound() {
        let sound = new Audio('https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/550960750349385730/1074758001048690698/pristine-609.mp3');
        sound.play();
    }

    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
        document.querySelector('textarea').focus();
    });

    // Add MutationObserver to detect new direct messages
    let observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
            let newMessage = mutation.target.querySelector('.direct-thread-message-renderer');
            if (newMessage) {
                playSound();
            }
        });
    });

    let chatContainer = document.querySelector('.direct-thread');
    if (chatContainer) {
        observer.observe(chatContainer, {
            childList: true,
            subtree: true
        });
    }
})();
```

any help, solution or hint is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: `// @resource ...` should be before the `// ==/UserScript==` line; the resource URL is dead

Comment: @double-beep i updated the code can you check whats the error now

Comment: Can you explain the problem in more detail? Are there any errors in the console? What is the current behaviour of the script?